# Firebase Realtime Database onDisconnect() Consistency

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I've got a near full-functioning realtime database presence system as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/presence) but I am encountering a few issues. It seems that people are remaining online even after having disconnected a while ago. I'm not sure why but I've opened up my security rules to unauthenticated requests temporarily to no avail. It could be due the bug described [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/174).

If the issue is the ladder, what would be the proper JavaScript implementation to avoid this issue? Is it a good solution to recreate the onDisconnect listener every 60 minutes? For reference, the code I'm using is shown below:

```
export function selfPresence(byUpdate) {
  onValue(ref(rtdb, '.info/connected'), (snap) => {
    isDBConnected = snap.val();
    if (snap.val() === true) {
      presencecon = push(ref(rtdb, `users/${user.uid}/connections`)); // Create new presence thing.
      onDisconnect(presencecon).remove();
      set(presencecon, true);
      onDisconnect(ref(rtdb, `users/${user.uid}/lastOnline`)).set(serverTimestamp());
      onDisconnect(ref(rtdb, `users/${user.uid}/currentlyListening`)).remove();
    }
  });
}
```

**MY SOLUTION**

- I could not figure out how to get RTDB to act consistently so I opted for the code below instead. Basically, it just updates a boolean at a specific path so that if/when the issue DOES happen, the next time the user is online, it will overwrite the failure with new online listener.

```
onValue(ref(rtdb, '.info/connected'), (snap) => {
    isDBConnected = snap.val();
    if (snap.val()) {
        onDisconnect(presencecon).set(false);
        presencecon = ref(rtdb, `users/${user.uid}/online`);
        isDBConnected = snap.val();
    }
    else {
        remove(presencecon);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) If the problem persists when you allow all users to write, it seems unlikely that it's due to the [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/174) you linked. --- 2) Are you saying the `users/${user.uid}/connections` connection remains even a few minutes after the connection has dropped?

Comment: Yes exactly, it remains permanently.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what could be causing that.  Can you set up a minimal repro of just the presence nodes on a site like jsbin or stackblitz, so I can have a look?

Comment: Since the code is so integrated, I think it'd be hard to isolate it unfortunately. The presence-related JS file is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/r0hin/parallel/main/app/js/presence.js), however. I've went and moved the relevant functions to the bottom and prefixed each relevant bit with // SO: so you can easily CTRL-F for it. Let me know if you want the full webapp. Thank you again so much for your help!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is this sufficient or should I be adding more information?

Comment: Just the repro I asked for, as without that it's unlikely I'll be able to reproduce it. We're getting some renewed eyeballs on the issue you linked, but as you said and I confirmed, we both doubt that it's the cause of your problems.

Comment: Can you share `The presence-related JS file` once again?. I am unable to open it. It is giving 404.

Comment: Sorry- here it is: https://pastebin.com/raw/XfE5gymj. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: Have you gone through stack overflow links? [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57011583/real-time-database-ondisconnect-not-executing-after-logging-out) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668292/firebase-when-ondisconnect-event-fire/30670928#30670928)?

Comment: I have and it doesn't seem like either solutions have worked. My only solution which is now implemented is to simply update a boolean which voids any multi-device support but at least it will correct the inconsistency of RTDB on the next login where the old value is replaced with a new listener.

Comment: I think it will be nice if you post your solution as an answer. It may help community members if someone comes across the same issue.

Comment: Added the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The below code updates a boolean at a specific path so that if/when the issue DOES happen, the next time the user is online, it will overwrite the failure with a new online listener.

```
onValue(ref(rtdb, '.info/connected'), (snap) => {
    isDBConnected = snap.val();
    if (snap.val()) {
        onDisconnect(presencecon).set(false);
        presencecon = ref(rtdb, `users/${user.uid}/online`);
        isDBConnected = snap.val();
    }
    else {
        remove(presencecon);
    }
}
```